# IQueryable<T> filtering by a list of IDs

Tags: c#, iqueryable

Let's say we have an `IQueryable<T>`. the `Where` clause can filter by single ID values, but how can I return an `IQueryable` based on a list of IDs?

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestIQueryableWithList()
{
    int ID1 = 1;
    List<int> IDs = new List<int> { 1, 3, 4, 8 };

    using (var db = new SellooEntities())            
    {
        // works fine as single value
        var iq = db.tblSearches.Where(x => x.seaUserId == ID1);

        // how can i do it to check for all the IDs ??
        foreach(int ID in IDs)
        {
            // this obviously wont work
            var iq = db.tblSearches.Where(x => x.seaUserId == ID);
        }
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Get data from `tblSearches` where `seaUserId` is in `IDs` list:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestIQueryableWithList()
{
    int ID1 = 1;
    List<int> IDs = new List<int> { 1, 3, 4, 8 };

    using (var db = new SellooEntities())            
    {
        var iq = db.tblSearches.Where(x => IDs.Contains(x.seaUserId);
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**Contains**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.contains.aspx)

```
var iq = db.tblSearches.Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.seaUserId));
```